# Receipt printing tabulation

Tags: java, android, formatting

Currently I am working on a Receipt Printing Tabulation code in Java/Android.

```
StringBuilder textData2 = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder textData3 = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder textData4 = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder textData5 = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder textData6 = new StringBuilder();
```

And I am calling these all textData to arrange bellow lines.

```
mPrinter.addCommand(new byte[] {0x0d, 0x0a});
textData2.append("-----------------------------------------------");
mPrinter.addText(textData2.toString());
mPrinter.addCommand(new byte[] {0x0d, 0x0a}); //LF
            //
mPrinter.addCommand(new byte[] {0x1b,0x44, 0x27, 0x00});
textData3.append("Bill no. 216381651273-5632");
mPrinter.addText(textData3.toString());
mPrinter.addCommand(new byte[] {0x09});//// HT

textData4.append("cash");
mPrinter.addText(textData4.toString());
mPrinter.addCommand(new byte[] {0x0d, 0x0a}); //LF

mPrinter.addCommand(new byte[] {0x1b,0x44, 0x27, 0x00});
textData5.append("Dine In");
mPrinter.addText(textData5.toString());
mPrinter.addCommand(new byte[] {0x09});//// HT

textData6.append("20 mar-17");
mPrinter.addText(textData6.toString());
mPrinter.addCommand(new byte[] {0x0d, 0x0a}); //LF
```

So, How can I define this `textdata` for once and use in multiple places ? Actually, I want to ignore using `textdata1/2/3/4/5.....`so on multiple times.

Comment: In the code snippet you posted it's not clear the purpose of those *textData#* variables. If you just use those variables as you shown here, than I think you don't need at all, just pass the string literal.

Comment: Everything looks hard-coded. It's not clear what the inputs are, and how the outputs are to be used.

Comment: @MarioSantini you are saying, to use `textData` as `String` and call it every place as`textData` insted of putting `textData1, textData2......20,21` ?

Comment: @GameOfThronesSuperFan not exactly, I'm telling you that in the code you post there is no meaning to use a variable, just place the string literal in *addText*.

Answer (score 1):

Doing

```
StringBuilder t = new StringBuilder();
t.append("some text");
t.toString();
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
"some text"
```

Unless you're calling append on the `StringBuilder` more than once, it's completely redundant.  So your code should read:

```
mPrinter.addCommand(new byte [] {0x0d, 0x0a});
mPrinter.addText("-----------------------------");
...
```

It would probably be a lot more readable if you stored all the text in a template file instead, but then you would have to have some way of figuring out what printer commands to intersperse with the text.